# Disable Hulu Desktop Startup Show

Tags: htpc, autoplay

I'm using Hulu Desktop as part of my HTPC. However, as anyone who has used it knows, whenever I start Hulu Desktop it chooses a show of Hulu's choice and starts playing it, which is incredibly annoying as I'm forced to listen to a show that I am not interested in while I scramble to try and find the show I want to watch. Does anyone know how to disable that "feature"? I've been searching on Google and I can't find anything. I found a preferences menu that had the option "Stop Autoplay of Shows?" and I set that to yes, but that's obviously referring to something different, as I still have it happening.

Any suggestions/fixes? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the start options to show Menu: Queue

[image: Hulu]

Comment: Or Menu: Popular. I prefer queue.